# Optimising SQL query, sums quantity in rows and sort it by the quantity but it is super slow when there is a lot of data

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, mysql-workbench

Will want to optimise this SQL query that takes about 40seconds to execute. The goal is to get the sum of all meals sold within a particular date, grouped by the meal ID

#### Query

```
    SELECT cm.meal_id as meal_id, 
          (SELECT sum(cm2.qty) 
           FROM cart_meals as cm2 
           where cm.meal_id = cm2.meal_id AND cm2.status = 'sold'
           AND (cm2.created_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01T00:00:00+01:00" AND "2022-07-01T23:59:59+01:00"))  AS sale 
    FROM cart_meals as cm
    WHERE cm.vendor_branch_id = "ef53f859-6bd1-44d2-821d-ea65c52aff30"
    AND cm.status = 'sold'
    AND (cm.created_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01T00:00:00+01:00" AND "2022-07-01T23:59:59+01:00") 
    GROUP by cm.meal_id
    order by sale desc LIMIT 5;
```

#### Result

```
112e1099-723e-49de-95b9-0b73dc5f27cc    4540
e0980ce2-870c-4fbe-8372-215d6c1a70ec    50
b1db2be5-9870-48bf-8fd9-9c18c47d11d1    36
ac06471c-7b4d-40f2-848d-782f634947c8    26
aa105091-75b5-4606-9719-efd9ecad3363    26
```

Execution Time: 44.105 s

Goal is to reduce it to less than 6 seconds or more

#### Table Info

```
CREATE TABLE `cart_meals` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `vendor_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `vendor_branch_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `meal_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `container_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` enum('unpaid','sold','refunded') COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT 'unpaid',
  `type` enum('table','pickup','deliver','pos') COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT 'deliver',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cart_meals_uuid_unique` (`uuid`),
  KEY `cart_meals_vendor_id_index` (`vendor_id`),
  KEY `cart_meals_vendor_branch_id_index` (`vendor_branch_id`),
  KEY `cart_meals_cart_id_index` (`cart_id`),
  KEY `cart_meals_meal_id_index` (`meal_id`),
  KEY `cart_meals_status_index` (`status`),
  KEY `cart_meals_type_index` (`type`),
  KEY `cart_meals_qty_index` (`qty`),
  KEY `cart_meals_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `cart_meals_cart_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `carts` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `cart_meals_meal_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`meal_id`) REFERENCES `meals` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `cart_meals_vendor_branch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_branch_id`) REFERENCES `vendor_branches` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `cart_meals_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES `vendors` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5830 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Comment: Please when asking optimization question always add table description (to check indexes) and explain plan `explain SELECT ....`

Comment: I am unclear what your intent is given the main query filters on branch but the sub query doesn't ie sales has nothing to do with branch other than reflecting sales by all branchs by product for any product sold by main query branch.

Comment: perhaps some combined indexes are needed such as one on status, created_at, and vendor_branch_id.  Also you're ordering by sale which is a generated column, so each record has to be evaluated in order to get the sale amount to limit by 5.

Comment: Based on your query I can think of adding two composite keys :`(vendor_branch_id,status,created_at)`  and `(meal_id,status,created_at)`. As I mentioned before without explain plan is hard to tell

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE cart_meals
    ADD INDEX(vendor_branch_id, status, created_at, meal_id),
    ADD INDEX(meal_id, status, created_at,  qty),
    DROP INDEX cart_meals_vendor_branch_id_index,
    DROP INDEX cart_meals_meal_id_index;
```

(DROPping is to get rid of redundant indexes due to the ADDs.)